# How do I pass an optional argument to a command called programmatically?

Tags: interactive, arguments

I would like to call a certain command from Emacs Lisp. This function takes two arguments plus a third optional argument. This third argument, when non-`nil`, doesn't ask for confirmation. I would like the programmatic call to behave just like the interactive call, except that I also want to bypass the confirmation prompt, by passing `t` as the third optional argument. How can I do this? I read the [interactive call](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Call.html) section of the [Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/index.html) manual but I was unable to find an answer to my question.

For concreteness, here is the command in question (from the [BBDB package](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/bbdb.html)):

```lisp
(defun bbdb-delete-field-or-record (records field &optional noprompt)
  "For RECORDS delete FIELD.
If FIELD is the `name' field, delete RECORDS from datanbase.
Interactively, use BBDB prefix \
\\<bbdb-mode-map>\\[bbdb-do-all-records], see `bbdb-do-all-records',
and FIELD is the field point is on.
If prefix NOPROMPT is non-nil, do not confirm deletion."
  ;; The value of FIELD is whatever `bbdb-current-field' returns.
  ;; This way we can identify more accurately what really needs
  ;; to be done.
  (interactive
   (list (bbdb-do-records) (bbdb-current-field) current-prefix-arg))
  (bbdb-editable)
  (unless field (user-error "Not a field"))
  (setq records (bbdb-record-list records))
  (let* ((type (car field))
         (type-x (if (eq type 'xfields)
                     (car (nth 1 field))
                   type)))
    (if (eq type 'name)
        (bbdb-delete-records records noprompt)
      (if (memq type '(firstname lastname))
          (user-error "Cannot delete field `%s'" type))
      (dolist (record records)
        (when (or noprompt
                  (y-or-n-p (format "delete this `%s' field (of %s)? "
                                    type-x (bbdb-record-name record))))
          (cond ((memq type '(phone address))
                 (bbdb-record-set-field
                  record type
                  ;; We use `delete' which deletes all phone and address
                  ;; fields equal to the current one.  This works for
                  ;; multiple records.
                  (delete (nth 1 field)
                          (bbdb-record-field record type))))
                ((memq type '(affix organization mail aka))
                 (bbdb-record-set-field record type nil))
                ((eq type 'xfields)
                 (bbdb-record-set-xfield record type-x nil))
                (t (error "Unknown field %s" type)))
          (bbdb-change-record record))))))
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0):

See `call-interactively` function, might do what you need. You would need to pass `(bbdb-do-records)` and `(bbdb-current-field)` manually.

EDIT:

I haven't really tried this, but the doc above says, if you run `C-u` before calling the command then it won't ask you for confirmation. So, in the code, you can do something like this:

```
(defun bbdb-delete-field-or-record-no-confirmation ()
  ""
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-prefix-arg 1))
    (call-interactively #'bbdb-delete-field-or-record)))
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I'm familiar with `call-interactively`, and one can do what I want with something like `(call-interactively (lambda () (interactive) (bbdb-delete-field-or-record (bbdb-do-records) (bbdb-current-field) t)))`, but I was interested in learning whether Elisp provides a better way of doing this. If there was no need to pass an argument, I could just do `(call-interactively 'bbdb-delete-field-or-record)`, so I was wondering whether there was a way of passing the optional argument only, without also having to pass the two other arguments explicitly, in this more convoluted way.

Comment: There is also `funcall`. But I really don't think you can bypass passing the positional arguments if you call the function from code. Also, I suppose it is just a typo, you don't need the `(interactive)` bit in the `call-interactively` as it is already being called interactively.